# Laravel: AuthController changes for Two factor authentication

Tags: laravel, two-factor-authentication

I am using the the built-in AuthController for Laravel 5.1 . I have integrated [antonioribeiro/google2fa](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa) to generated QR code and verify the key. I have also made changes in my postLogin function, so that after the credentials are verified user will be rediredted to TFA key entering form.

My question is where and how should I handle the TFA Key response. What should be the best practices so security of my app is not compromised.